# Use absolute values not relative values in scale_fill_gradientn

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, heatmap

I would like a smooth gradient starting from red at 0 to white at 0.5 to green at 1.

My data doesn't cover this full range, and it seems `scale_fill_gradientn` takes the `values` argument to be relative to the data, rather than their actual values.

The plot produced below shows white above 0.5 rather than at 0.5. How can I correct this and set the gradient limits to the specific values I write, rather than relative to the data?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
expand_grid(x=1:10, y=1:10) %>%
  mutate(val = rnorm(100, mean = 0.55, sd = 0.05)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = val)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(val, 3))) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red","white","green"),
                       values = scales::rescale(c(0.0, 0.5, 1.0)))
```

[image: heatmap_example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set the `limits` parameter of `scale_fill_gradientn`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
expand_grid(x=1:10, y=1:10) %>%
  mutate(val = rnorm(100, mean = 0.55, sd = 0.05)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = val)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(val, 3))) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red","white","green"),
                      limits = c(0.0, 1.0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works for my specific example with a midpoint at 0.5. What about the general case? Say I want white at 0.45? Or extending to more than three colours?

Comment: @conor that's when you add `rescale` - you use limits _with_ scale, not instead of it. The limits just say what you want to set the minimum and maximum points to. The rescale sets where abouts on a scale of minimum to maximum you want the changes to occur.